# Roblox trying to make an invisibility potion but it only works once

Tags: roblox

I was going to ask this on the roblox dev forum but they have some level system thing

I wrote this code which should make any character that touches the part "juice" turn invisible then copy a local script into their player character which waits then turns them visible and destroys itself. the code works once however if you try it a second time the event function runs and even prints after each line with no errors but it doesn't change any of the player part transparencies again.
here is the main script.

```
local healthpack = script.Parent.juice
healthpack.CanCollide = false
healthpack.Anchored = true
healthpack.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
print"hit"

if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") and healthpack.Transparency ~= 1 then

    print"if"
    local scrip = script.Parent.LocalScript
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    local copy = scrip:Clone()
    local tran = .99
    local efrem = script.Parent.effectremover:Clone()
    print"var"
    hit.Parent.LeftFoot.Transparency = tran
    print"1"
    hit.Parent.LeftHand.Transparency = tran
    print"2"
    hit.Parent.LeftLowerArm.Transparency = tran
    print"3"
    hit.Parent.LeftLowerLeg.Transparency = tran
    print"4"
    hit.Parent.LeftUpperArm.Transparency = tran
    print"5"
    hit.Parent.LeftUpperLeg.Transparency = tran
    print"6"
    hit.Parent.LowerTorso.Transparency = tran
    print"7"
    hit.Parent.RightFoot.Transparency = tran
    print"8"
    hit.Parent.RightHand.Transparency = tran
    print"9"
    hit.Parent.RightLowerArm.Transparency = tran
    print"10"
    hit.Parent.RightLowerLeg.Transparency = tran
    print"11"
    hit.Parent.RightUpperArm.Transparency = tran
    print"12"
    hit.Parent.RightUpperLeg.Transparency = tran
    print"13"
    hit.Parent.UpperTorso.Transparency = tran
    print"14"
    hit.Parent.Head.Transparency = tran
    print"15"
    hit.Parent["Pal Hair"].Handle.Transparency = tran
    print"16"
    efrem.Parent = hit.Parent.Humanoid
    print"17"
    copy.Parent = player.PlayerGui
    print"18"
    script.Parent.Heal:Play()
    print"19"
    healthpack.Transparency = 1
    script.Parent.stem.Transparency = 1
    script.Parent.bottle.Transparency = 1
    script.Parent.cork.Transparency = 1
    script.Parent.rim.Transparency = 1
    wait(10)
    healthpack.Transparency = 0
    script.Parent.stem.Transparency = .45
    script.Parent.bottle.Transparency = .45
    script.Parent.cork.Transparency = 0
    script.Parent.rim.Transparency = .35
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow!  I'm not sure 100% what you want, but it looks like there is an issue with your if statement where it says `healthpack.Transparency ~= 1`.  What it looks like you're doing is setting the transparency to `.99`:

```lua
local tran = .99
```

and then checking if it's `1`:

```lua
healthpack.Transparency ~= 1
```

So, if you change your `if` statement:

```lua
if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") and healthpack.Transparency ~= .99 then
```

I suggest defining your `tran` variable outside of your if statement:

```lua
-- Set transparency here instead:
local tran = .99

if (hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") and healthpack.Transparency == tran) then
    -- ...
end
```

Comment: so what this script is supposed to do is when the object "Healthpack" (script.Parent.juice) is touched it runs the function containing the if statement                                                    
"if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") and healthpack.Transparency ~= 1 then" if both of these are true (the first one verifies that the object that touched it is a part of a player, the second one makes sure the potion object is still visible because it turns invisible for a set amount of time after being used) then it makes the parts of the player transparencies "tran"

Comment: after setting the players parts to "tran" the script clones two scripts and places in in the player (one in playergui, and one in the character under "Humanoid" one script displays the gui "potion picked up" and deletes itself the other waits 60 seconds and turns the player visible again and deletes itself. after the main script clones these scripts it sets healthpack.Transparency to 1 so the potion is inactive. the problem i have is that the sript works once perfectly but after a player uses it it no longer makes them invisible with no errors and while printing all of those prints.